# Parsing ip addresses in php

Tags: php, parsing

I am trying to get the number of active connections (Real Time) from a log file by IP connected and having a Play status but instead, it's giving me the total number of IP with status play. The number doesn't decrease at all. Keeps on increasing as soon as a new ip is added. How can I fix it? Here my code:

```
$stringToParse = file_get_contents('wowzamediaserver_access.log');
preg_match_all('/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/', $stringToParse, $matchOP);
echo "Number of connections: ".sizeof(array_unique($matchOP[0]));
```

HERE IS THE LOG:

```
2013-10-30  14:54:36    CET stop    stream  INFO    200 account1    -   _defaultVHost_  account1    _definst_   149.21  streamURL   1935    fullStreamURL   IP_ADDRESS_1    http (cupertino)    -   
2013-10-30  14:56:12    CET play    stream  INFO    200 account2    -   _defaultVHost_  account1    _definst_   149.21  streamURL   1935    fullStreamURL   IP_ADDRESS_2    rtmp (cupertino)    -   
2013-10-30  14:58:23    CET stop    stream  INFO    200 account2    -   _defaultVHost_  account1    _definst_   149.21  streamURL   1935    fullStreamURL   IP_ADDRESS_2    rtmp (cupertino)    -   
2013-10-30  14:58:39    CET play    stream  INFO    200 account1    -   _defaultVHost_  account1    _definst_   149.21  streamURL   1935    fullStreamURL   IP_ADDRESS_1    http (cupertino)    -
2013-10-30  14:59:12    CET play    stream  INFO    200 account2    -   _defaultVHost_  account1    _definst_   149.21  streamURL   1935    fullStreamURL   IP_ADDRESS_2    rtmp (cupertino)    -
```

I want to be able to count the IP whenever it has a "PLAY" status and don't count it whenever it's "STOP"

```
    2013-10-30  14:59:00    CET play    stream  INFO    200 tv2vielive  -   _defaultVHost_  tv2vielive  _definst_   0.315   [any]   1935    rtmp://tv2vie.zion3cloud.com:1935/tv2vielive    78.247.255.186  rtmp    http://www.tv2vie.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf WIN 11,7,700,202    92565864    3576    3455    1   0   0   0   tv2vielive  -   -   -   -   -   rtmp://tv2vie.zion3cloud.com:1935/tv2vielive/tv2vielive rtmp://tv2vie.zion3cloud.com:1935/tv2vielive/tv2vielive -   rtmp://tv2vie.zion3cloud.com:1935/tv2vielive    -


2013-10-30  14:59:04    CET stop    stream  INFO    200 tv2vielive  -   _defaultVHost_  tv2vielive  _definst_   4.75    [any]   1935    rtmp://tv2vie.zion3cloud.com:1935/tv2vielive    78.247.255.186  rtmp    http://www.tv2vie.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf WIN 11,7,700,202    92565864    3576    512571  1   7222    0   503766  tv2vielive  -   -   -   -   -   rtmp://tv2vie.zion3cloud.com:1935/tv2vielive/tv2vielive rtmp://tv2vie.zion3cloud.com:1935/tv2vielive/tv2vielive -   rtmp://tv2vie.zion3cloud.com:1935/tv2vielive    -
```

Any solutions? I have even tried the first answer solution but getting "0" play connections.

```
$stringToParse = file_get_contents('wowzamediaserver_access.log');

$pattern = '~^.* play.* ( ([0-9]{1,3}+\.){3,3}[0-9]{1,3}).*$~m';
preg_match_all($pattern, $stringToParse, $matches);

echo count($matches[1]) . ' play actions';
```

But whenever I use my code:

```
$stringToParse = file_get_contents('wowzamediaserver_access.log');
preg_match_all('/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/', $stringToParse, $matchOP);
echo "Number of connections: ".sizeof(array_unique($matchOP[0]));
```

I am getting "Number of connections: xxxxx(actual count of IPs).
My concern is that I only need the count of IPs with PLAY status. If that IP changes to STOP then it wont count.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add the log:

Comment: how can I attach a file? Want to attach the log

Comment: You cannot attach files on this platform. Post an excerpt from the file.

Comment: You need to count only the IP registers in the file for less than 5 mins per example.

Comment: I just posted a piece of the log just to give you guys an idea of the log structure

Comment: You need to count only the IP registers in the file for less than 5 mins per example. –  Pierre Emmanuel Lallemant
What if the IP connects for more than 5min? I want to be able to count the IP whenever it has a "PLAY" status and don't count it whenever it's "STOP"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$pattern = '~^.* play.* (([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}).*$~m';
preg_match_all($pattern, $stringToParse, $matches);

echo count($matches[1]) . ' play actions';
```

It will extract the IP addresses of those lines which contain the literal `play` and count them.

Comment: Currently the log you've posted contains no ids. It contains only the string `IP_ADDRESS_1` (and so far).. Can you show a real world log?

Comment: $log = file_get_contents('wowzamediaserver_access.log');

$pattern = '~^.* play.* ( ([0-9]{1,3}+\.){3,3}[0-9]{1,3}).*$~m';
preg_match_all($pattern, $log, $matches);

echo count($matches[1]) . ' play actions';

Comment: I've updated the pattern after you have copied it. Copy the pattern again and try

Comment: I have edited your post. I have added $stringToParse = file_get_contents('wowzamediaserver_access.log');
but still showing "0 play actions"

Comment: I've rejected that edit as it is makes no sense to add this line (because readers will not have that file).. Again, I've tested it with the 2 lines of output that you've posted and it works. Seems you are doing something wrong...

Comment: ok but what about this variable "$stringToParse"? you still need to specify the file name or path. right?

Comment: of course **you** will need the `file_get_contents()`.. but it is not related to my answer

Comment: exactly, I have added $stringToParse = file_get_contents('wowzamediaserver_access.log'); to your answer but still getting "0 play actions".
    http://tv2vie.zion3cloud.com/tv2vie/logs/

Comment: Yes, I understand that. As I said, seems you are doing something wrong.. The regex pattern works (have tested it with the lines of log you have posted).. I cannot help any further